# Method is not getting executed in ASP.NET Wizard

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class that inserts a `TextBox` value and a `FileUpload` image into the SQL Server. I'm executing all the class in the `Wizard1_FinishButtonClick` event. I have 4 steps in Wizard. All the classes are getting executed and inserted other than `InsertCert()` class. 
I executed same codes in a simple .aspx page and the values are inserting into the DB.

Where 'm I going wrong? Following is the class and Wizard1_FinishButtonClick.

```
public void Insertcert()
        {
            String KKStech = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KKSTech;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KKStech);
            String insertstring2 = @"insert into Cert(CertName, CertLogo)
                                       values(@CertName, @CertLogo)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertstring2, conn);
            cmd.CommandText = insertstring2;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            try
            {
                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    byte[] productImage = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CertName", TextBox18.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CertLogo", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = productImage;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
```

This is the final class where all the classes are inserted.

```
 protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            InsertInfo();
            Insertcert();
            Insertaddress();
            Insertskills();

        }
```

Comment: Perhaps one of your Methods is throwing an Exception and therefore giving the impression that the other method(s) are not being executed.. have you put break points in the code and stepped through..? why not write write the exception(s) to a log or return in a Response so that you can at least see what the ex.Message is..??

Comment: @DJKRAZE All the classes are working fine and is getting inserted..

Comment: Step through it in the debugger and check that FileUpload1.HasFile is true. Also you do not need the catch, as you are only throwing the exception again. The SqlCommand needs disposing too; I suggest you use a using block rather than try...finally.

Comment: do you mean all the Methods / procedures are working fine..? what do you mean when you say "All the Classes" refactor your question

Comment: Sorry, I meant all the 'methods' are getting executed except Insertcert();

Comment: @ShellShock I am not aware of how to use break points. How'd I check using the breakpoints? All I know is placing the red sphere near the margin and pressing F10 after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the cursor on the "if (FileUpload1.HasFile)" line and hit F9; this will put a breakpoint on that line (you'll see a red circle in the left hand margin). Now debug your program (F5). When the breakpoint is hit, hover the mouse over the "HasFile" and you should see a tool tip which gives the value. If the value is false, this explains why the insert is not happening.